# Angular $http.query use array as params?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, arrays

I have an Angular 1 application where a user can select several items by clicking on a checkbox. When he clicks a particular button, these Ids are aggregated as this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.orders, function (order, id) {
    if (order.export) {
        ids.push(order.id);
    }
});
```

Now I want to query these Ids in my php api action, but how can I transmit all id's to my apiAction? I tried it with **$http.query** (`$scope.items = Items.query({ 'ids' : ids});`), but this does not work as it creates a strange url which can not be parsed.

Then I tried it with: **$http.save** and there I can transfer the ids to my api action, but I also need to return the result back to my application in order to show it on the frontend, but with using $http.save this does not seem to be possible, as I always get a `orderBy:notarray` error.

So how can I use `$http.save` and get a proper array in return or use $http.query with an array with multiple ids in the params?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is `$http.query` and `$http.save`? I don't see anything remotely like that in the angular `$http` docs here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular $http call...

```js
params: {
    id: JSON.stringify(ids) 
  }
```

Comment: Hmm, then I get this query result: itemsApi?ids=%5B1816,1817%5D

When I do var_dump($ids); I get this result: string(11) "[1816,1817]"

So I need to substr [ and ] and then do an explode. Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your array into comma separated string and then pass that string into your php api and then you can get back your array in php. E.g.,

Angular side,

```
ids.toString()
```

PHP side,

```
explode(",",$query_param);
```